# When to use a negative index for substring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When does it make sense to call `SUBSTRING` with a zero or negative index, considering the same result can be achieved with an index of 1. These queries produce identical results. They truncate the rightmost character. But why does TSQL even produce a result for the 3rd, 4th and 5th queries.

```
SELECT LEFT('ab,', LEN('ab,') - 1)              -- makes sense

SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', 1, LEN('ab,') - 1)      -- makes sense

SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', 0, LEN('ab,'))          -- why?

SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -1, LEN('ab,') + 1)     -- why?

SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -2, LEN('ab,') + 2)     -- why?
```

Results:

```
----
ab


----
ab


----
ab


----
ab


----
ab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Substring Documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187748.aspx)

**Syntax for substring:**

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

start

> Is an integer or bigint expression that specifies where the returned characters start. ***If start is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in expression***. In this case, the number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either the sum of start + length- 1 or 0. If start is greater than the number of characters in the value expression, a zero-length expression is returned.

length

> Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many characters of the expression will be returned. **If length is negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated**. If the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned

Now coming to your question..

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', 0, LEN('ab,'))          -- why?
---start at zero and get values till whatever count of  `LEN('ab,')` this returns

SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -1, LEN('ab,') + 1)     -- why?
--We know if start is negative,substring starts at 0 from above documentation


SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -2, LEN('ab,') + 2)     -- why?
--We know if start is negative,substring starts at 0 from above documentation
```

**when to use Negative Substring:**
As you can see ,it doesn't matter when you use negative start or zero,SQL will always start from `0` in both of the cases..

There are no use cases,i can  thinkoff, when the behaviour of specfying negative length is helpfull..

this mighttt be added to documentation,since some times,when we want to add  length of  start dynamically  and specify some thing like below..

```
CHARINDEX('somesearchitem', 'Expression, 5)-10
```

The above expression will some times lead to negative values,in this case SQL will start from starting of expression unlike throwing an error like in the case of length

Comment: Yes it is documented behavior. But is it useful behavior? Does it ever makes sense to use it?

Comment: @AnthonyFaull: I don't see any use cases ,since both are same

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When we have 0 or a negative value in the start parameter then the character index starts with 2 so the index of character 'a' is 2 and the index of character 'b' is 3.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', 0, LEN('ab,')) -- is equivalent to 
SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', 0, 3) -- so 0 + 3 = 3 so o/p will be upto index 3 i.e. ab

SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -1, LEN('ab,') + 1) -- is equivalent to 
SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -1, 4) -- so -1 + 4 = 3 so o/p will be ab

SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -2, LEN('ab,') + 2) -- is equivalent to
SELECT SUBSTRING('ab,', -2, 5) -- so -2 + 5 = 3 so o/p will be ab
```